# Inner class problem - Java unable to find "InnerClass2" when Nested within Main

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

Noob here. I have tried the following code, but it appears that Java cannot find InnerClass2 when nested. I could not find any guide on how to fix this issue. I also tried `InnerClass2 in = Main.new InnerClass2();` but it did not work either. Thoughts?

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   InnerClass2 in = new InnerClass2();
   class InnerClass2 {
     InnerClass2(){
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: You can not declare classes inside methods..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare a class within a method. You could instead declare it inside the `Main` class:

```java
public class Main {
  public static class InnerClass2 {
    // class details
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InnerClass2 in = new InnerClass2();
  }
}
```